# Database not getting dropped with hibernate3-maven-plugin

Tags: hibernate, hbm2ddl, sessionfactory

I'm using the hibernate3-maven-plugin to generate my schema before running tests, and it is successfully creating the schema, but is not successfully dropping it.

My plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>hbm2ddl</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <components>
            <component>
                <name>hbm2ddl</name>
                <implementation>annotationconfiguration</implementation>
            </component>
        </components>
        <componentProperties>
            <implementation>jpaconfiguration</implementation>
            <persistenceunit>JpaPersistenceUnit</persistenceunit>
            <configurationfile>src/test/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml</configurationfile>
        </componentProperties>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>mysql</groupId>
           <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
           <version>5.1.5</version>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

My hibernate xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/db_test</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

As you can see, I'm using hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop, which the documentation states should drop the db at SessionFactory close time.

However, when I run my tests for the second time, I see the following Errors:

```
[ERROR] Error #1: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'stations' already exists
[ERROR] Error #1: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'track_scans' already exists
```

(I currently only have two entities, so this seems appropriate)

I'm not sure where to go from here.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting a functional solution by adding `<drop>true</drop>` to the componentProperties section of the plugin configuration.